# Why does the count() function in python only allow '3 arguments' and how to overcome

Tags: python, count

Would anyone kindly explain why my special complex code below doesn't work? I've tried having a search on google but cannot find an answer that I understand. An error is shown saying my count() only allows '3 arguments' apparently. So wondering if there is a simple way around this. I know there is a 'string.count' function among others but I cannot seem to get them to work.

Many thanks for your time in helping!

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator")

name1 = input("What is your name?")

name2 = input("What is their name?")


name_1_lower_case = name1.lower()

name_2_lower_case = name2.lower()

both_names = name_1_lower_case + name_2_lower_case


calculate_true = both_names.count("t", "r", "u", "e")

calculate_love = both_names.count("l", "o", "v", "e")



total_score = str(calculate_true) + str(calculate_love)

print(total_score)
```

Comment: the code isn't "complex" at all, there are only 3 kinds of statements. Why don't just read the [count method's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)? What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: The 'special complex' part was a joke... But I appreciate your response and signposting to this document. I will give it a read. Thanks

Comment: It was for a very basic code task. I should have included more of the instructions: Take both people's names and check for the number of times the letters in the word TRUE occurs.

Then check for the number of times the letters in the word LOVE occurs.

Then combine these numbers to make a 2 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator")

name1 = input("What is your name?")
name2 = input("What is their name?")

name_1_lower_case = name1.lower()
name_2_lower_case = name2.lower()
both_names = name_1_lower_case + name_2_lower_case

calculate_true = sum(both_names.count(s) for s in "true")
calculate_love = sum(both_names.count(s) for s in "love")

total_score = str(calculate_true) + str(calculate_love)

print(total_score)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply with a very helpful solution. I do wonder, however, if its a little inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

The count method takes the substring (or single character) to find, plus, optionally, the start and end of the indices to search. You are trying to send it a whole load of different substrings to find.

You could probably accomplish what you want with

```
total_score = sum( [ both_names.count( c ) for c in "true" + "love" ] )
```

Comment: but this provides different results. According to the official formula, true love is calculated by converting each word score to a string and them adding the strings. So scores 2 and 3 will gives a total score of 23 and not 5.

Comment: Ah, I never realised there was an "official formula" for true love! Sounds vaguely 1984esque.

Comment: The official formula is biased, since it makes "true" much more important than "love" by concatenating strings instead of adding numbers. But that's how it is: one of the great mysteries of love.

Comment: Yes that's right - apologies for not adding further information. I also wonder why cant it deal with multiple different substrings to find? Technically, shouldn't it work?

Comment: No, it's only set up for one substring, so "technically", it wouldn't work. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use Counter to meet you requirement.

```py
from collections import Counter

print("Welcome to the Love Calculator")

name1 = input("What is your name?")
name2 = input("What is their name?")

name_1_lower_case = name1.lower()
name_2_lower_case = name2.lower()

both_names = name_1_lower_case + name_2_lower_case

counter = Counter(both_names)
calculate_true = sum([counter[char] for char in "true"])
calculate_love = sum([counter[char] for char in "love"])

total_score = str(calculate_true) + str(calculate_love)

print(total_score)
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for this. I will have a go using your suggestion.